# Why is this php code working this way

Tags: php, wordpress

I realize this is a wordpress plugin but I'm hoping someone can help me out with the overall php structure of my code.

```
<?php    
  add_filter( 'wprss_auto_create_terms', 'filter_categories', 10, 3 );
  /**
  * Filter categories to only allow "Plugin Reviews".
  * Change "Plugin Reviews" into "Plugins" if found.
  */
  function filter_categories( $categories, $taxonomy, $source_id ) {
  // Check for feed source 3878
    if ( $source_id == '3878' ) {
      // Loop all categories
      foreach( $categories as $i => $category ) {
        // If "Plugin Reviews" is found, change it to "Plugins"
        if ( $category['name'] == 'Plugin Reviews' )
          $categories[$i]['name'] = 'Plugins';
          // If not "Plugin Reviews", remove it
        else unset( $categories[$i] );
      }
    }
    // Return the categories
    return $categories;
  }
```

I'm able to change any feed category names with the name "Plugin Reviews" to "Plugins" because all current posts in the feed currently contain the category "Plugin Reviews". If I try a category that all the posts do not have they are all call Uncategorized regardless if some have the category name or not. What am I missing and any ideas how this could be fixed?

Comment: You have an if that matches a string, and replaces it, followed by an else which removes the category (unset).  Just delete the else line.

Comment: So for input `$categories = array(
 array('name'=>'Plugin Reviews'),
 array('name'=>'Other')
);` the output appears to be: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Plugins ) )` (i.e. the second array with name != 'Plugin Reviews' is removed). What is the desired output?

Comment: Each feed has multiple category tags <category> example; http://www.vogue.in/feed/  I'd like to be able to go through a feed and say if a post has <category><![CDATA[Designers]]></category> in it change the category to Fasion regardless of the other categories assigned to that post or any of the other posts in the feed.